# Capturing everything between <pre> </pre> tags

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am reading in a .html file:

```
const htmlin = String(fs.readFileSync(inputHtml) || '');

const splitted = htmlin.split(/<pre.*>/);
splitted.shift();

const justPost = splitted.join('').split('</pre>');
justPost.pop();
```

but I am looking for a way to match all the text within

```
aaa <pre> xxx </pre> bbb <pre> foo </pre> ccc
```

and also match the text outside. So that I can get two arrays:

```
['aaa ', ' bbb ', ' ccc']
```

and

```
[' xxx ', ' foo ']
```

how can I do this with regex or some other method?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use regex replace function and capturing group.

```
<pre>(.*?)(?=<\/pre>)|(?:^|<\/pre>)(.*?)(?=$|<pre>)
```

- `<pre>(.*?)(?=<\/pre>)` - Matches text between `pre` tags. ( g1 )
- `(?:^|<\/pre>)(.*?)(?=$|<pre>)` - Matches text out of `pre` tags. (g2)

```js
let str = `aaa <pre> xxx </pre> bbb <pre> foo </pre> ccc`
let inner = []
let outer = []

let op = str.replace(/<pre>(.*?)(?=<\/pre>)|(?:^|<\/pre>)(.*?)(?=$|<pre>)/g, function (match,g1,g2){
  if(g1){
    inner.push(g1.trim())
  } 
  if(g2){
    outer.push(g2.trim())
  }
  return match
})

console.log(outer)
console.log(inner)
```

Comment: the last regex `(?:^|<\/pre>)(.*?)(?=$|<pre>)` (Matches text out of pre tags. ) is not too good, because it does not remove the <pre> tag  from such this exemple: `sadsa <pre>const justPost = splitted.join('').split('</pre>');`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a regex, you might use the dom or a domparser.

For example, create a div and set the innerHTML property to your html. Then loop the childnodes and get the innerHTML or the textContent.

For example:

```js
let htmlString = `aaa <pre> xxx </pre> bbb <pre> foo </pre> ccc`,
  pre = [],
  text = [];
let div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = htmlString;

div.childNodes.forEach(x => {
  if (x.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
    text.push(x.textContent.trim())
  }
  if (x.nodeName === "PRE") {
    pre.push(x.innerHTML.trim());
  }
});

console.log(pre);
console.log(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used re.DOTALL to find the data between

```
 and
```

then split on carriage return

```
txt="""111 abc<pre>seven
eight
nine
ten
eleven
twelve</pre>
<pre> one 
two 
three 
four 
five 
six </pre>def"""
results= re.findall(r'<pre>(.*?)</pre>', txt,re.DOTALL)
print(results)
word_list=[]
for item in results:
    print(item)
    words=item.split("\n")
    for word in words:
        word_list.append(word)
        
print(word_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you may have html tags inside <pre> - personally I would put a marker that does not exist in the html at the end tag ¬</pre> like this.
Then I would search from the beginning of the pre tag

```
const myTextWithMarker = myText.replace('</pre>', '¬</pre>');
const regResult = myTextWithMarker.match(/<pre( [^>]*)?>([^¬]*)/);
const myContent = regResult[0]
```